# How to search word from the starting sentence

Tags: android

i have a code for search word on array but i did not know how to detect search word from the fist letter of the sentence.

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {return  false; }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {


            newText = newText.toLowerCase();

            final ArrayList<DictObjectModel> filteredList = new ArrayList<DictObjectModel>();

            for (int i = 0; i < wordcombimelist.size(); i++) {

                final String text = wordcombimelist.get(i).toLowerCase();
                if (text.contains(newText)) {

                    filteredList.add(new DictObjectModel(wordcombimelist.get(i),meancombimelist.get(i)));
                }
            }
            adapter = new CustomAdapter(filteredList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


            return true;
        }
    });
```

But i want to get those string also where the input string matches not only in the first characters but also any where in the string? How to do this?

Comment: `contains()` should do the trick, what result are you currently getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not so clear. So I am giving two conditions.

If you are trying to search for the presence of query **anywhere** in the text, use `text.contains(query)`

If you are trying to search for the presence of query **at the beginning** of the text, use `text.startsWith(query)`

Comment: Thanks alot, i replace to text.startsWith(query)